# Importing Large iGraph Memory Exhausted

Tags: python, igraph

I'm trying to import a large LGL file (~2GB) and I am attempting to import this in igraph using

```
graph = Graph.Read_Lgl("Biggraph.lgl")
```

The error it is throwing is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph.py", line8, in <module>
    graph = Graph.Read_Lgl("Biggraph.lgl")
igraph.core.InternalError: Error at foreign.c:359: Parse error in LGL file, line 9997 (memory exhausted), Parse Error
```

I'm unsure as to what exactly is going on here.  The memory exhausted error is making me think that the memory allocated to python (or the underlying C) is being used up when trying to read the file, but it almost happens **instantly**, like it isn't even trying to do much.  Maybe it's looking at the file size and saying 'woah, can't do that.'

Seriously though, I have no idea what is happening.  What I assumed from iGraph is that it can handle extremely large graphs, and I dont think my graph is too large for it.

I did generate the lgl file myself, but I believe I have the syntax correct.  This error doesn't really seem like there is a problem with my lgl file, but I could be wrong ("Parse error" kind of scares me).

I just figured I'd try here and see if anyone more keen on how iGraph operates would know how to quickly solve this problem (or extend the memory).  Thanks.

Comment: One of the igraph authors here. Your problem is indeed weird; I'd appreciate if you could get in touch and send me a snippet of the graph (say, the first 10000 lines) so I could start debugging it. Check my profile for my email address (or if you can't see it, then check my homepage, it should be there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, the poster has found a bug in the igraph library and we are working on a fix right now. The problem is caused by a right-recursive rule in the `bison` parser specification for the LGL format. Once we have an official patch for it in the trunk of the project, I will post the URL of the patch here should others run into the same problem.

---

**Update**:
The URLs to the patches are:

- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~igraph/igraph/0.5-main/revision/1696 (for igraph 0.5.x)
- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~igraph/igraph/0.6-main/revision/2543 (for igraph 0.6)